# Installing gems to which Ruby with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

How does one control which Ruby a gem is installed to using rbenv? Or could there be a central place accessible to all Rubies? I am just running Ruby scripts not Rails. rbenv-gemset seems to be for that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The gem is installed into whatever your currently selected Ruby is. E.g.

```sh
rbenv shell 2.0.0-p247
gem install bundler  # bundler is installed for Ruby 2.0.0-p247 only
rbenv shell 1.9.3-p447
gem install bundler  # bundler is installed for Ruby 1.9.3-p447 only
```

Comment: Thank you. And your example suggests that I can just change the shell to make those changes. I didn't want to change the global Ruby to install. And further your example suggest that bundler only works on the Ruby you're working in. I hadn't looked at bundler, but since it manages Rubies, I thought that might be the way to go, but seems not for my non-Rails use.

Comment: Bundler does not manage Ruby versions, it manages gem dependencies.

Comment: Thanks again. That's kind of what I thought. I'm still having trouble with installing to system and 1.8.7. Need to spend some time seeing what is where because I install a gem and then it's not available.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on: `rbenv-gemset` would be for organizing your gems *within the same ruby version*. Only `rbenv` controls which ruby you install your gems to...